# Edit/Delete rows of SQLite-data-base in android

Tags: android, database, sqlite, edit

I'm using [this tutorial](http://androidsolution4u.blogspot.ie/2013/09/android-populate-listview-from-sqlite.html) for writing an Android program that shows the database's field in a ListView. Now I want to edit them (edit/delete) with ActionMode's buttons.

Would you please help me write editing and deleting code?
This is my project code:

MyActivity.java class:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
private ListView listView;
private DataBaseClass classDB;
private SQLiteDatabase sqlDB;
private ArrayList<String> Id = new ArrayList<String>(); // vows id
private ArrayList<String> number = new ArrayList<String>(); // vows text

ListView.MultiChoiceModeListener callback;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    callback = new ListView.MultiChoiceModeListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            mode.setTitle("Demo");
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.action_mode_menu, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.editBTN:
                editBTN();//edit method
                mode.finish(); 
                break;
            case R.id.deleteBTN:
                 AlertDialog.Builder build = new AlertDialog.Builder(MyActivity.this);
                build.setMessage("Do you want to delete ?\r\n" + adapter.getPropertiesByPosition(adapter.selectedViewsPositions.get(0), "title"));

                if (adapter.selectedViewsPositions.size() == 1) {
                    //build.setTitle("Do you want to delete ?");

                    build.setMessage("Do you want to delete ?\r\n" + adapter.getPropertiesByPosition(adapter.selectedViewsPositions.get(0), "title"));
                } else {
                    //build.setTitle("Delete ?");
                    build.setMessage("Delete these " + adapter.selectedViewsPositions.size() + " saved pages ?");
                }

                build.setPositiveButton("Delete",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                ProgressDialog pd = new ProgressDialog(MyActivity.this);
                                pd.setMessage("Deleting items...");
                                pd.setIndeterminate(false);
                                pd.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
                                pd.setMax(adapter.selectedViewsPositions.size());
                                pd.setCancelable(false);
                                pd.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);

                                pd.show();

                                classDB = new DataBaseClass(MyActivity.this);
                                sqlDB = classDB.getWritableDatabase();

                                for (Integer position: adapter.selectedViewsPositions) {
                                    sqlDB.delete(DataBaseClass.TABLE_NAME, DataBaseClass.COLUMN_ID + "=" + adapter.getPropertiesByPosition(position, "id"), null);
                                    pd.setProgress(adapter.selectedViewsPositions.indexOf(position));

                                }
                                sqlDB.close();


                                pd.hide();
                                pd.cancel();

                                //Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this,"Deleted " + gridAdapter.selectedViewsPositions.size() + " saved pages", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                                mode.finish();
                            }
                        });

                build.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                                int which) {
                                dialog.cancel();
                                mode.finish();
                            }
                        });
                AlertDialog alert = build.create();
                alert.show();                   
                break;
            case R.id.doneBTN:
                //!?change background color of list view
                break;
            }
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(ActionMode mode,
                int position, long id, boolean checked) {
        }
    };

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView);
    listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);
    listView.setMultiChoiceModeListener(callback);

    classDB = new DataBaseClass(this);
}

// ***************** Menu Button for adding VOW
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.add, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.add_menu:
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                AddActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("update", false);
        startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    displayData();
    super.onResume();
}

private void displayData() { // displays data from SQLite
    sqlDB = classDB.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor mCursor = sqlDB.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "
            + DataBaseClass.TABLE_NAME, null);

    Id.clear();
    number.clear();
    if (mCursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Id.add(mCursor.getString(mCursor
                    .getColumnIndex(DataBaseClass.COLUMN_ID)));
            number.add(mCursor.getString(mCursor
                    .getColumnIndex(DataBaseClass.COLUMN_NUMBER)));

        } while (mCursor.moveToNext());
    }
    MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(this, Id, number);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    mCursor.close();
}
```

DataBaseClass.java:

```
public class DataBaseClass extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
static String DATABASE_NAME = "user's information";
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "vowing";
public static final String COLUMN_ID = "id";
public static final String COLUMN_NUMBER = "number";

public DataBaseClass(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String CREATE_TABLE="CREATE TABLE "+TABLE_NAME+" ("+COLUMN_ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "+COLUMN_NUMBER+" TEXT)";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(db);

}
```

MyAdapter.java class:

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context context;
private ArrayList<String> MId;
private ArrayList<String> Mnumber;

public ArrayList<Integer> selectedViewsPositions = new ArrayList<Integer>();
public Cursor dbCursor;

public MyAdapter(Context c , ArrayList<String> id, ArrayList<String> number){
    context=c;
    MId=id;
    Mnumber=number;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return MId.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int i) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    Holder mHolder;
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    if (view == null) {
        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        mHolder = new Holder();
        mHolder.txt_id = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.id);
        mHolder.txt_Number = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.number);
        view.setTag(mHolder);
    } else {
        mHolder = (Holder) view.getTag();
    }
    mHolder.txt_id.setText(MId.get(i));
    mHolder.txt_Number.setText(Mnumber.get(i));

    return view;
}

public class Holder {
    TextView txt_id;
    TextView txt_Number;
}

public String getPropertiesByPosition(int position, String type) {

    dbCursor.moveToPosition(position);

    if (type.equals("id")) {
        return dbCursor.getString(dbCursor.getColumnIndex(DataBaseClass.COLUMN_ID));
    }

    else if (type.equals("numbert")) {
        return dbCursor.getString(dbCursor.getColumnIndex(DataBaseClass.COLUMN_NUMBER));
    }

    else { return null; }
}
```

AddActivity.java class:

```
public class AddActivity extends Activity {
private EditText addNUM;
private DatePicker addDATE;

private Button insertBTN;
private Button deleteBTN;

private DataBaseClass classDB;
private SQLiteDatabase sqlDB;

private String id;
private String number;
private boolean isUpdate;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.add_activity);

    classDB = new DataBaseClass(this);

    addNUM = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.addNum);

    insertBTN = (Button) findViewById(R.id.insert);
    deleteBTN = (Button) findViewById(R.id.deleteBTN);

    insertBTN.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            number=addNUM.getText().toString().trim();

            if(number.length()>0 && number.length()>0){
                saveData();
            }else {
                AlertDialog.Builder alertBuilder=new AlertDialog.Builder(AddActivity.this);
                alertBuilder.setTitle("Invalid Data");
                alertBuilder.setMessage("Please, Enter valid data");
                alertBuilder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
                alertBuilder.create().show();
            }
        }
    });

    isUpdate=getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("update");
    if(isUpdate){
        id=getIntent().getExtras().getString("ID");
        number=getIntent().getExtras().getString("Number");
        addNUM.setText(number);
    }

}

private void saveData(){  //save data into SQLite
    classDB = new DataBaseClass(this);
    sqlDB=classDB.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values=new ContentValues();

    values.put(DataBaseClass.COLUMN_NUMBER,number);

    System.out.println("");
    if(isUpdate)
    {
        //update database with new data
        sqlDB.update(DataBaseClass.TABLE_NAME, values, DataBaseClass.COLUMN_ID+"="+id, null);
    }else {
        //insert data into database
        sqlDB.insert(DataBaseClass.TABLE_NAME, null, values);
    }
    //close database
    sqlDB.close();
    finish();
}
```

i have 3 questions:
1-how to edit the whole row with EDIT button of ActionMode button?
2- how to delete he whole row with DELETE button of ActionMode button?
3- how to change the color of listView's row that clicked on DONE button of ActionMode button?

This is LogCat:

```
06-04 09:36:28.847    1884-1884/? V/AudioPolicyManagerBase﹕ setOutputDevice() output 2 device 0002 force 0 delayMs 0
06-04 09:36:28.847    1884-2151/? D/AudioHardwareTinyALSA﹕ OutALSA::setDevice: mode = 0, newDevice=0x2, currentDevice=0x2 ,force= 0
06-04 09:36:29.077    1884-1884/? V/AudioPolicyManagerBase﹕ setOutputDevice() output 2 device 0000 force 0 delayMs 184
06-04 09:36:39.592    1884-2154/? V/AudioPolicyManagerBase﹕ setOutputDevice() output 2 device 0002 force 0 delayMs 0
06-04 09:36:39.607    1884-2151/? D/AudioHardwareTinyALSA﹕ OutALSA::setDevice: mode = 0, newDevice=0x2, currentDevice=0x2 ,force= 0
06-04 09:36:40.192   1884-25939/? V/AudioPolicyManagerBase﹕ setOutputDevice() output 2 device 0000 force 0 delayMs 184
06-04 09:38:36.412    1884-1884/? V/AudioPolicyManagerBase﹕ setOutputDevice() output 2 device 0002 force 0 delayMs 0
06-04 09:38:36.417    1884-2151/? D/AudioHardwareTinyALSA﹕ OutALSA::setDevice: mode = 0, newDevice=0x2, currentDevice=0x2 ,force= 0
06-04 09:38:36.647    1884-1884/? V/AudioPolicyManagerBase﹕ setOutputDevice() output 2 device 0000 force 0 delayMs 184
06-04 09:38:38.317    1884-2181/? V/AudioPolicyManagerBase﹕ setOutputDevice() output 2 device 0002 force 0 delayMs 0
06-04 09:38:38.572    1884-2181/? V/AudioPolicyManagerBase﹕ setOutputDevice() output 2 device 0000 force 0 delayMs 184
06-04 09:38:52.677    1884-2181/? V/AudioPolicyManagerBase﹕ setOutputDevice() output 2 device 0002 force 0 delayMs 0
06-04 09:38:52.687    1884-2151/? D/AudioHardwareTinyALSA﹕ OutALSA::setDevice: mode = 0, newDevice=0x2, currentDevice=0x2 ,force= 0
06-04 09:38:52.917    1884-1884/? V/AudioPolicyManagerBase﹕ setOutputDevice() output 2 device 0000 force 0 delayMs 184
06-04 09:38:54.287    1884-2154/? V/AudioPolicyManagerBase﹕ setOutputDevice() output 2 device 0002 force 0 delayMs 0
06-04 09:38:54.542    1884-2154/? V/AudioPolicyManagerBase﹕ setOutputDevice() output 2 device 0000 force 0 delayMs 184
06-04 09:38:54.767    1884-1884/? V/AudioPolicyManagerBase﹕ setOutputDevice() output 2 device 0002 force 0 delayMs 0
06-04 09:38:55.032    1884-1884/? V/AudioPolicyManagerBase﹕ setOutputDevice() output 2 device 0000 force 0 delayMs 184
06-04 09:38:56.827   1884-28672/? V/AudioPolicyManagerBase﹕ setOutputDevice() output 2 device 0002 force 0 delayMs 0
06-04 09:38:59.892    1884-1884/? V/AudioPolicyManagerBase﹕ setOutputDevice() output 2 device 0002 force 0 delayMs 0
06-04 09:39:00.052    1884-2176/? V/AudioPolicyManagerBase﹕ setOutputDevice() output 2 device 0002 force 0 delayMs 184
06-04 09:39:00.162    1884-2176/? V/AudioPolicyManagerBase﹕ setOutputDevice() output 2 device 0000 force 0 delayMs 184
06-04 09:39:01.672    1884-1884/? V/AudioPolicyManagerBase﹕ setOutputDevice() output 2 device 0002 force 0 delayMs 0
06-04 09:39:01.927    1884-1884/? V/AudioPolicyManagerBase﹕ setOutputDevice() output 2 device 0000 force 0 delayMs 184
06-04 09:39:13.257    1884-2176/? V/AudioPolicyManagerBase﹕ setOutputDevice() output 2 device 0002 force 0 delayMs 0
06-04 09:39:13.267    1884-2151/? D/AudioHardwareTinyALSA﹕ OutALSA::setDevice: mode = 0, newDevice=0x2, currentDevice=0x2 ,force= 0
06-04 09:39:13.497    1884-2176/? V/AudioPolicyManagerBase﹕ setOutputDevice() output 2 device 0000 force 0 delayMs 184
06-04 09:39:14.782    1884-2154/? V/AudioPolicyManagerBase﹕ setOutputDevice() output 2 device 0002 force 0 delayMs 0
06-04 09:39:15.052    1884-2154/? V/AudioPolicyManagerBase﹕ setOutputDevice() output 2 device 0000 force 0 delayMs 184
06-04 09:45:21.852    1884-2176/? V/AudioPolicyManagerBase﹕ setOutputDevice() output 2 device 0002 force 0 delayMs 0
06-04 09:45:21.867    1884-2151/? D/AudioHardwareTinyALSA﹕ OutALSA::setDevice: mode = 0, newDevice=0x2, currentDevice=0x2 ,force= 0
06-04 09:45:23.502   1884-18891/? V/AudioPolicyManagerBase﹕ setOutputDevice() output 2 device 0000 force 0 delayMs 184
06-04 09:47:09.712    2233-2347/? I/ActivityManager﹕ Killing proc 18535:com.example.draft_vow/u0a211: force stop
```

Comment: This tutorial didn't teach how to editing and deleting. It only create a default database, that can only save 1 or 2 column data. I recommen you read [this article](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html), that will teach you how to use SQLite in android and some goods practices.

Comment: @Paulo, That tutorial _does_ say how to to editing and deleting.

Comment: @JonasCz. May I ask you, please help me? ipost my codes.

Comment: I will try your code later. What you need to do is get the ids of the selected items from the multichoice listener, and then delete your items from database. BTW, I wrote an app which do this, see https://github.com/jonascz/save-for-offline in `mainActivity.java`.

Comment: Did the code in the link I posted help you ?

Comment: thanks alot for app and its sources. i'm working in your app's code(delete part),but i am not sure to find out mine.

Comment: @JonasCz.what is the "selectedViewsPositions" in DisplayAdapterin your source code?

Comment: @MinaDahesh, This is the "position" of the item which is selected, ie. It's a list which says "the first, third, tenth is selected", so we know what is selected. Sorry I missed your comment.

Comment: @JonasCz. refer to your app's code,i change my codes, but as i click on deleteBTN my app has stoped. would you please help me to resolve it?

Comment: @MinaDahesh add the LogCat to your question. Without it, I cannot help you.

Comment: @JonasCz. i wrute them above. please check them.thanks!

Comment: @Mina Unfortunatly I don't know anything about `OutALSA` or Audio on Android, so I can't really help. Anything else in LogCat ?

Comment: i don't use any audio in my app too!

Answer (score 1):

*NEW EDIT*
sorry for the delay XD

data base AgendaSqlite.java

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class AgendaSqlite extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    //Sentencia SQL para crear la tabla de Usuarios
    String sqlCreate = "CREATE TABLE vowing (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, number INTEGER)";

    public AgendaSqlite(Context context, String name, CursorFactory factory,int version) {
        super(context, name, factory, version);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(sqlCreate);
    }

    @Override
    public void onOpen(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        super.onOpen(db);
        if (!db.isReadOnly()) {
            // Enable foreign key constraints
            db.execSQL("PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON;");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        //eliminamos la version anterior de la tabla
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS vowing");

        //aqui creamos la nueva version de la tabla
        db.execSQL(sqlCreate);
    }
}
```

to edit/delete, here, you need a editText or something to get the number you are going to delete/edit

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
private ListView listView;
private DataBaseClass classDB;
private SQLiteDatabase sqlDB;
private ArrayList<String> Id = new ArrayList<String>(); // vows id
private ArrayList<String> number = new ArrayList<String>(); // vows text


String C1="", C2="", C3="", C4="", C5="", C6="";
String Fin="";
SQLiteDatabase db;
Cursor cursor;
final String TABLA_PRINCIPAL = "vowing"; //table
final String NOMBRE_BASE_DATOS = "userInformation.db"; //data base
AgendaSqlite usdbh;
Int number=0, numberCorrect=0;
Int id=0, idCorrect=0;


ListView.MultiChoiceModeListener callback;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


    String ArchivoDB = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/"+NOMBRE_BASE_DATOS;
    usdbh = new AgendaSqlite(this, ArchivoDB, null, 1);//
    db = usdbh.getWritableDatabase();

    callback = new ListView.MultiChoiceModeListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            mode.setTitle("Demo");
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.action_mode_menu, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.editBTN:
                editBTN();//edit method
                mode.finish(); 
                break;
            case R.id.deleteBTN:
                deleteBTN(); //!?delete method
                mode.finish();                     
                break;
            case R.id.doneBTN:
                //!?change background color of list view
                break;
            }
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(ActionMode mode,
                int position, long id, boolean checked) {
        }
    };

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView);
    listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);
    listView.setMultiChoiceModeListener(callback);

    classDB = new DataBaseClass(this);
}

// ***************** Menu Button for adding VOW
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.add, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.add_menu:
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                AddActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("update", false);
        startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    displayData();
    super.onResume();
}
/*
private void displayData() { // displays data from SQLite
    sqlDB = classDB.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor mCursor = sqlDB.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "
            + DataBaseClass.TABLE_NAME, null);

    Id.clear();
    number.clear();
    if (mCursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Id.add(mCursor.getString(mCursor
                    .getColumnIndex(DataBaseClass.COLUMN_ID)));
            number.add(mCursor.getString(mCursor
                    .getColumnIndex(DataBaseClass.COLUMN_NUMBER)));

        } while (mCursor.moveToNext());
    }
    MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(this, Id, number);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    mCursor.close();
}*/
editBTN(){
            //get the number to delete from a edit text or something
            Update();
            String[] args = new String[]{C1};
            db.execSQL("UPDATE " + TABLA_PRINCIPAL + " SET number='" + number + "' WHERE _id=?", args);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Updating!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}

    void Update() /////// contarenacion de los datos
    {
        C1=""; C2=""; C3=""; C4=""; C5=""; C6="";
        Fin="";
        cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from "+TABLA_PRINCIPAL, null);

        if (cursor.getCount() != 0) {
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    C1 = cursor.getString(cursor
                            .getColumnIndex("_id"));//get _id
                    if(id==C1){
                        idCorrect=C1;
                    }

                    C2 = cursor.getString(cursor
                            .getColumnInteger("number"));//get number
                    if(number==C2){
                        numberCorrect=C2;
                    }
                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }
        }
        cursor.close();
    }

    deleteBTN(){
        //get the numberto a delete from a edit text or something
        Update();
        String[] args = new String[]{C2};
        db.execSQL("DELETE FROM "+ TABLA_PRINCIPAL+" WHERE number=?", args);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "delete!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

---

if you are trying to delete use the database.exeSQL to do it, here you go:

```
delete.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            name = paciente.getText().toString();//get the nameof what you are trying to delete
            if (name.matches("")) { //check if it's empty
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Whatever you want/ALERT", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }else{
                String[] args = new String[]{name};
                db.execSQL("DELETE FROM "+ YOUR_TABLE+" WHERE ColumnName=?", args);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Whatever you want", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                espacioHistorial.setText("");
            }
        }
    });
```

to update is similar in a button:

```
String[] args = new String[]{nombre};//name or id whatever you want
                    db.execSQL("UPDATE " + TABLA_PRINCIPAL + " SET sintomas='" + sintomas + "', diagnostico='"+diagnostico1+"' WHERE nombre_paciente=?", args); //using SET you say that the column will be update with a new string
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ALERT", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

hope this help, see ya

Comment: @CarlosCarrizales.what's the "args"?is it one of my array's data?

Comment: in both of my examples args, is a string i got from a edit Text, in this case a person/name something to know where to delete/update

Comment: in my proje I have 3 strings, so I should have 3 string?

Comment: talking about the update, not exactly, for example, you have String S1,S2,S3, in the part that says: db.execSQL("UPDATE "+TABLA_PRINCIPAL+" SET column='"+S1+"', column2='"+S2+"',column3='"+S3+"'where ...");
add just to the SET the string and column's string you are going to update

Comment: @CarlosCarrizales.i forgot to say that i prepare a form in AddActivity.java class for filling my dataBase's fields.so for editing/updating part, i want get back data to  AddActivity...please help me?

Comment: @user3671748  ok, but which Activity is AddActivity?, is the java class you posted above? anyway, let's set this information first,
imagine, you have your own activity WHERE you are waiting for the data you want to edit/erase from the table,
First, get the name of the person you are looking for to delete it.
Second, in your activity (can be named AddActivity) add a button with a listener for edit or delete.
Third add my codes for it
that's all! :D 
if you still have problems with it, why not to post all the activity here to help you out more especifically, see ya

Comment: @CarlosCarrizales.i post my code.i have 3 questions:1-how to edit the whole row with EDIT button of ActionMode button?/2- how to delete he whole row with DELETE button of ActionMode button?/3- how to change the color of  listView's row after clicking on DONE button of ActionMode button?-please help me,how can i solve it?

Comment: @MinaDahesh sorry, was taking a break XD that's the code for create a data base in my way, and the way to edit/delete a data from the data base, see ya

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to useSQLiteOpenHelper
Just use ORM
SugarOrm is easy and simple

That's like array, so there is "add", "delete" methods,
Also you can edit by get set methods into class of item and use "save" to update row of table

Google it